# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP showing wrong timezone in SQL Azure database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

I have an SQL database connected to an Azure server, the timezone is set to UTC and the location is set to UK south, when I run the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP command on the SQL database it returns a time at UTC-1:00. I assume this is an Azure based issue since when I run the same command on a locally hosted SQL server I get the correct timezone. Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated. All I can think is the location being set to UK south assumes I'm in some overseas UK territory hence giving the wrong timezone so my next step is to make a new database on azure to host it but change the location since you cant change it once it has been created.

[image]

This is the query on the azure server

[image]

This is the query on my local server. Both of these queries were made at 17:43 UTC

Comment: UTC will be same irrespective of location, there is not possible to change by server configuration or database configuration. Could you share the screenshot of output of your query?

Comment: Hi Saideep I have updated the post with a picture of the queries

Comment: Creating MySql server with the UK south location according to the the timezone is set to UTC. As we connected MySql Server  and tried to get UTC current time which the location is set to be UK South of the mysql server and we get the result as per the expectations when we run `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` command. Can you please check again.

Comment: Hi saideep, my mistake, the server is set at UTC but the time zone I want is BST, do you now how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample procedure to get **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** in AZURE SQL DATABASE.

Creating MySql server with the UK south location according to the the timezone is set to UTC.
[image]
Currently, the default time zone on Azure SQL DB is UTC. Unfortunately, there is not possible to change by server configuration or database configuration.

Azure SQL Database does not support time zone settings; it always follows UTC.
Use AT TIME ZONE in SQL Database if you need to interpret date and time information in a non-UTC time zone.